# How to optimize my code in mysql stored procedure when I use one search condition in many times?

Tags: mysql, sql

In my stored procedure in mysql,I have to search the data created in yesterday.Now my code is here:

```
DECLARE  v_CurrentDate, v_LastDate datetime ;
set v_CurrentDate=curdate();
set v_LastDate=date_sub(curdate(),interval 1 day);
-- student
select count(*) from student where where createtime>=v_LastDate
and createtime< v_CurrentDate;
-- worker
select count(*) from worker where where createtime>=v_LastDate
and createtime< v_CurrentDate;
 -- food
select count(*) from food where where createtime>=v_LastDate
and createtime< v_CurrentDate;
-- vegetables
select count(*) from vegetables where where createtime>=v_LastDate
and createtime< v_CurrentDate;
```

I have four same condition,can I write the code more optimize ?

Comment: Not, you can not optimize this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the procedural languages, wrapping SQL, `tables` and `where clauses` are not first class citizens. You cannot assign them to variables, return them from a function, pass them as parameters or concatenate them.

So no, you cannot optimize this, unless you resort to generating this programm from a more concise source, using string processing or dynamic sql. This is a good way to shoot you in the foot.

Answer (score 0):

No there's no good way to optimize this code.  You could change some things so there would be less *code*, but it would either be slower to run or harder to maintain.  This is often the case with SQL, it will require more code than seems necessary.  What you are doing is the right way to do it however.